# kotlin merge two maps by overwriting values

Tags: kotlin

If I have the below two maps:

```
val x = mapOf("a" to 10, "b" to 5)
val y = mapOf("a" to 4)
val result = //
```

How can I get the result to be: `{a=4, b=5}`? I want the value to be overwritten if the key exists.

Comment: `val result = x + y`

Comment: @IR42 please make this an answer. This is the simplest and most idiomatic way to do this.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`val result = x + y` does exactly what you need, the second parameter (`y`) will overwrite the values with the same keys from the first parameter (`x`)

Answer (score 0):

```
val result = x.toMutableMap().apply { putAll(y) }
```

Comment: While `(x + y)` looks cleaner, this code does literally the same after all the inlining, except `putAll` returns nothing.

Comment: Right! edited to use apply since putAll returns unit. Still using + is cleaner. Didn't realize that worked with maps.